# Cannot an object of abstract type - override won't work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Howdy fellas I have bad news: I don't know what's going on at all.

I'm trying to make a bunch of StarWarsShip objects and a bunch of StarTrekShip objects and make them fight each other in a linked list. Skipping a bunch of boring details, C++ is not letting me create the StarWarsShip/StarTrekShip objects because they are abstract - something I only vaguely know the meaning of as of a couple Google searches ago.

Anyway here's some code:

StarWarsShip.h

```
#include "SpaceShip.h"

class StarWarsShip : public SpaceShip
{
private:
  string uni; //this ship is in the star wars universe
  string pilot; //this is the captains name
  int atp; //this is how much damage the ship will do
  int hullM; //this is the strength of the ship initially
  int hullC; //this integer keeps track of how much more damage the ship can take
  bool shields; //are the shields up?
  //string shipDeath; //The message that will display when the ship is destroyed
  string lastWords; //The last words of the Star Wars pilot

public:
  StarWarsShip();
  ~StarWarsShip();

  void setStats(string P, int atPwr, int hullMax, bool shlds, string LW); //sets stats of the ship

  string getLeader(); //returns the name of the pilot
  int getAttackPower(); //returns how much attack power the ship has
  int getCurrentHull(); //returns how much health the hull still has? hull? health? hullth?
  int getMaxHull(); //gets the maximum hull value of the ship
  bool takeDamage(int amount); //takes damage if the ship has the hull value to handle it
  bool getShields();  //lets the object know if the shields are down
  string getUniverse();//ship is in the star wars universe
  //string getStatus(); //prints the status of the ship
  //string finalMessage(); //prints the final message of the ship
};
#endif
```

SpaceShip.h

```
class SpaceShip
{
public:
  virtual ~SpaceShip() {};
  virtual string getLeader() const = 0;
  virtual int getAttackPower() const = 0;
  virtual int getCurrentHull() const = 0;
  virtual int getMaxHull() const = 0;
  virtual bool takeDamage(int amount) const = 0;
  virtual bool getShields() const = 0;
  virtual string getUniverse() const = 0;
  //virtual string getStatus() const = 0;
  //virtual string finalMessage() const = 0;
};
#endif
```

FlightManager.cpp (but just the constructor)

```
#include "FlightManager.h"

using namespace std;

FlightManager::FlightManager(string fileName)
{
  ifstream inFile(fileName);
  if (inFile.is_open())
  {
    cout << "File found. Reading in...\n";
  }
  else
  {
    //quit
  }
//now i read in stuff from a file, not actually important
  while (getline(inFile, line))
  {
    //declare temp variables that will be used to parse and organize data
    string tUniverse;
    string tLeader;
    string tATP;
    string tPar4;
    string tPar5;
    string tPar6;

    //begin parsing list of data and compiling into objects
    char c;
    int j = 0;
    for(char&c : line)
    {
      if(c == ',') j++;
      else if (c == ' ')
      {
        tPar6 += c;
        continue;
      }
      else if (j == 0) tUniverse += c;
      else if (j == 1) tLeader += c;
      else if (j == 2) tATP += c;
      else if (j == 3) tPar4 += c;
      else if (j == 4) tPar5 += c;
      else if (j == 5) tPar6 += c;
    }

    //Declare a new ship object each time a new line is parsed
    //Add the ship to the list of ships

    if (tUniverse == "StarWars")
    {
//NEXT LINE BIG ERROR YIKES
        StarWarsShip newShip = new StarWarsShip();
        newShip.setStats(tLeader, stoi(tATP), stoi(tPar4), toBool(tPar5), tPar6);
        //Parameters are : void StarWarsShip::setStats(string P, int atPwr, int hullMax, bool shlds, string LW)
        //input format is <universe>,<captain name>,<attack power>,<number of crew>,<max hull value>,<shield status>

        spaceBattle.addBack(newShip);
    }
    else
    {
//NEXT LINE BIG ERROR YIKES
        StarTrekShip* newShip = new StarTrekShip();
        newShip->setStats(tLeader, stoi(tATP), stoi(tPar4), stoi(tPar5), toBool(tPar6));
        //Parameters are : (string C, int atPwr, int crewNumber, int hullMax, bool shlds)
        //input format is <universe>,<captain name>,<attack power>,<number of crew>,<max hull value>,<shield status>

        spaceBattle.addBack(newShip);
    }

    length = spaceBattle.getLength();

    if(inFile.eof())
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```

And my error is:

```
FlightManager.cpp:66:49: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘StarWarsShip’
         StarWarsShip newShip = new StarWarsShip();
In file included from FlightManager.h:10:0,
                 from FlightManager.cpp:8:
StarWarsShip.h:16:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘StarWarsShip’:
 class StarWarsShip : public SpaceShip
       ^
In file included from StarWarsShip.h:14:0,
                 from FlightManager.h:10,
                 from FlightManager.cpp:8:
SpaceShip.h:18:18: note:        virtual std::string SpaceShip::getLeader() const
   virtual string getLeader() const = 0;
```

And then it continues to roast my code. Do I need to make my StarWarsShip class not abstract, and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Additionally I tried to use override but when I tried to add the "override" at the end of my method declarations it simply told me it failed to override.

Comment: StarWarsShip need implement all SpaceShip pure virtual function.Otherwise it can not new. And don't forget your pure virtual funciotn has const suffix.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I added the const to my StarWarsShip methods but now I'm getting a different error.
FlightManager.cpp:66:49: error: conversion from ‘StarWarsShip*’ to non-scalar type ‘StarWarsShip’ requested
         StarWarsShip newShip = new StarWarsShip();

Comment: Could you fix by yourself? Or you could modify your quesion add the error message.

Comment: new StarWarsShip() return a pointer of StarWarsShip not a StarWarsShip.

Comment: If my answer help you,please accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StarWarsShip need implement all SpaceShip pure virtual function.

And don't forget your pure virtual funciotn has const suffix.

So in subclass need const too.

At last,new StarWarsShip() return a pointer of StarWarsShip not a StarWarsShip.

```
StarWarsShip newShip = new StarWarsShip(); //error
StarWarsShip newShip;                      //change to this.
```